# Android Room. Insert into table without FOREIGN KEY causes FOREIGN KEY Exception :-O

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Insert into table without any foreign keys causes foreign key exception. Very strange, and I I a bit got in shock why.

My classes.

Station.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = Station.TABLE_NAME)
data class Station (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid") var rowid: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "stationName") var stationName: String?,
)
companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "stations"
    }
}
```

StationDao.kt

```
interface StationDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(station: Station): Long
}
```

Tag.kt

```
data class Tag(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid") var rowid: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tagName") var tagName: String?,
) {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "tags"
    }
}
```

TagDao.kt

```
interface TagDao {
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(tag: Tag): Long
}
```

StationWithTags.kt

```
data class StationWithTags(
    @Embedded var station: Station,
    @Relation(
        entity = Tag::class,
        parentColumn = "rowid",
        entityColumn = "rowid",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = StationTagMap::class,
            parentColumn = "stationIdMap",
            entityColumn = "tagIdMap"
        )
    )
    var tags: List<Tag>,
) {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_NAME = "stations_t"
    }
}
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["stationIdMap", "tagIdMap"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Station::class,
            parentColumns = ["rowid"],
            childColumns = ["stationIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Tag::class,
            parentColumns = ["rowid"],
            childColumns = ["tagIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class StationTagMap(
    var stationIdMap: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var tagIdMap: Long
)
```

RoomDB.kt

```
    entities = [
        Station::class,
        Tag::class,
        StationTagMap::class,
    ], version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class RoomDB : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun stationDao(): StationDao
    abstract fun tagDao(): TagDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: RoomDB? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): RoomDB {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): RoomDB {
            val db: RoomDB?
            db = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, 
                 RoomDB::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .addCallback(
                        object : Callback() {
                            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                                super.onCreate(db)
                                val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<StationsWorker>()
                                    .build()
                                WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
                            }
                        })
                    .build()
            }

            instance = db
            return db
        }
    }
}
```

In my Worker after creating database
I just try to insert one row into `stations` table
just for test purposes:

StationsWorker.kt

```
...
override suspend fun doWork() {
    try {
        val database = RoomDB.getInstance(applicationContext)
        val rowid = database.stationDao()
            .insert(Station(rowid = 0, stationName = "First station"))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating stations database")
        Result.failure()
    }
    Result.success()

}
...
```

And it causes exception `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)`.
I do not understand why 'cause `stations` table does not have any FOREIGN KEYS
Other tables do have. But this insert does not touch them.

Before I added this relation `StationWithTags` sure It worked well

Comment: What is being done in the CallBack? Perhaps that is where the FK exception is taking place. Perhaps add logging or a try/catch within the Callback. Also perhaps add e.printStackTrace() to the catch clause of the doWork.

Comment: @MikeT inthe CallBack as it seems from the code I attached is being done
StationsWorker.doWork()

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is with whatever is being done in the Callback (at a guess that is where the FK exception is occurring).

Running a modified version of your code with (and for convenience on the main thread using `.allowMainThreadQueries`) :-

```
            .addCallback(
                object : Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onCreate(db)
                        //val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<StationsWorker>()
                        //    .build()
                        //WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
                    }
                })
```

Then via App Inspection :-

[image]

Comment: What exactly you modified?

Answer (score 0):

Unexpectedly, the issue was solved by unusual way.
I replaced beta Android Studio instead of stable on (EEL) I used.
After it's build my code unchanged and run it all worked well as it seems without errors.